# Basic Matrix Equation Manipulation (Using The Commutative Scalar-Matrix Property)

Tags: inner-products, matrix-equations

The commutative law for scalar-matrix multiplication states that:
*s* **A** = **A** *s*

And the associative law for matrix multiplication states that:
(**AB**)**C** = **A**(**BC**)

Finally the dot product of two column vectors states that: **a**$\cdot$**b** = **a**$^T$**b**

Using the above rules are we allowed to manipulate an equation as such:
(**a**$\cdot$**b**)**c** = **c**(**a**$^T$**b**) = (**c** **a**$^T$)**b** where **a**, **b** and **c** are column vectors.

Specifically we use the commutative scalar-matrix rule to change the order in which we multiply by **c**, but in doing so we are no longer creating a scalar from **a** $\cdot$ **b**, so does the scalar-matrix rule still hold?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Why not try a few examples to see that it works?

Comment: So, have you tried any examples?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have tried a few examples and it seems to work out for any nxn matrices, but when I thought about it where A was a nxm matrix, and B was a mxl matrix, and finally C was a qxt matrix where l != n and l != m then there seems to be a problem. Multiplying C by a scalar isn't an issue, but you cannot multiply A by C, and thus the above manipulation is invalid.

Comment: If $l\ne q$ then you can't do $BC$, so all bets are off. But in your question, $a,b,c$ are all column vectors, so I don't see what any other kind of matrix has to do with it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh that makes sense the law of associativity doesn't hold up if the multiplication between the matrices are invalid, such as when the number columns of one matrix doesn't match the rows of the next, so you could still calculate $c(a^tb)$ but not $(ca^t)b$. Manipulation of matrix equations is so fascinating because unlike standard algebraic equations your options for manipulation only become available when you inspect the qualities of the matrices present outside of the actual equation, which can change throughout the manipulation!

Comment: Moreover when manipulating the equation its important to consider the present state of the matrices, because as long as its valid when you make the manipulation it will still be valid during your future manipulations. Such as changing multiplication order by treating the dot product as a scalar, even though the final manipulation removes the presence of the scalar. Thank you for your help I think I understand now

Comment: Good. But the number of rows of $A^tB$ is the same as the number of rows of $A^t$, so if you can calculate $C(A^tB)$, then you can also calculate $(CA^t)B$.